# With zero errors, why CSS styling are not reflecting on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The image of the product in the product component is not rendering the styles given to it in the `Product.css` file.

Header and Home component styling are working fine but not the Product styling.

I checked everything, seems like everything is fine but still scratching my head to find the blind spot.

OUTPUT

[image: Product container image]

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Product.css";


  const Product = () => {
       return (
       <div classname='product'>
        <div className='product__info'>
            <p>The Lean Startup:
                How Constant Innovation 
                Creates Radically successful Businesses
            </p>

            <p className='product__price'>
                <small>$</small><strong>19.99</strong>
            </p>

            <div className='product__rating'>
                <p className='product__star'>⭐</p>
                <p className='product__star'>⭐</p>
                <p className='product__star'>⭐</p>
                <p className='product__star'>⭐</p>
                <p className='product__star'>⭐</p>

                
            </div>
        </div>

        <img  alt='book' src='https://images-na.ssl-images- 
amazon.com/images/I/51Zymoq7UnL._SX325_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'
 />

            <button >
                Add to basket
            </button>               
       </div>
      );
     }
     export default Product;
        
    
    
  Product.css file

.product{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  margin:10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height:400px;
  min-width:300px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:red;
 }

.product > img {
 max-height:200px;
 width:100%;
 object-fit:contain;
 margin-bottom:15px;
}


.product__price{
height:100px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.product > button{
background: #f0c14b;
border:1px solid;
margin-top:10px;
border-color: #a88734 #9c7e31 #846a29;
color: #111;
}

.product__info{
height: 100px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Here I am rendering the Product component in the `Home.js` file

```
import React from 'react'
import './Home.css';
import Product from './Product.js';

const Home = () => {
return (
    <div className='home'>
        <div className='home__container'>
         <img className='home__image' 
            alt='amazon-prime' src="https://images-eu.ssl- 
 images-amazon.com/images/G/02/digital/video/
 merch2016/Hero/Covid19/Generic/
 GWBleedingHero_ENG_COVIDUPDATE__XSite_1500x600_PV_en- 
 GB._CB428684220_.jpg"/>
            
             <div className='home__row'>
                
              <Product/>  
                
             </div>
         </div>         
      </div>
     )
   }

 export default Home;
```

Comment: Typo in your very first div, should be className.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `classname` prop should be `className` (`camelCase`).

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname),

> To specify a CSS class, use the `className` attribute. This applies to all regular DOM and SVG elements like `<div>`, `<a>`, and others.